# Pandas: How to get dummy variable columns from union of two dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, categorical-data, dummy-variable

I have two dataframes, each with the same variables and row length, but with the categorical variables (object columns) sometimes having different realizations in one versus the other.

Here is what I mean.

```
Frame 1 | categorical_1 | categorical_2 |||  Frame 2 | categorical_1 | categorical_2
row 1   | blue          | flakes        |||  row 1   | blue          | flakes
row 2   | red           | cheerios      |||  row 2   | red           | flakes
row 3   | blue          | cheerios      |||  row 3   | green         | flakes
```

As you can see in my basic illustration above, green appears only in the second dataframe, whereas cheerios only appear in my first dataframe.

Basically, I need a way to create dummy variable columns considering the "variable ranges" of both dataframes (or more), so I cannot just call `pd.get_dummies` on either of them.

Comment: What's the desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no other function in pandas can help you do this. As you mentioned, `pd.get_dummies` can only create dummies in one dataframe.

Do you have an index or a different ID in your dataframe?

if you do, you can sub the `categorical_2` and merge them into one dataframe. Then you can use `pd.get_dummies` and finally match it back to the original dataframe according to the distinct index or ID.

If you don't, I think the only way to handle this is coding manually.